# How to understand these english sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

I learn english with free bbc courses. Now I am on unit 11 http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/upper-intermediate/unit-11/session-2.

I really don't understand these sentences:

> 1. Taylor Swift opened the show and by the time it ended she had three Grammys, including album of the year, for 1989.

I can't make out **for 1989**. What it means?

Next sentence I can't translate is:

> 2. She told young women in the music business to persevere and take credit for their own talents.

What means phrase **to persevere and take credit for their own talents**?

Comment: "1989" is the title of Taylor Swift's album that won three Grammys.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. What means sentence 2?

Comment: @Hellion: Is that something you happen to *know?* So far as I'm concerned, it's quite possible at least one of the Grammys she won in that year might have been for something like *Best live act* or *Most promising newcomer*, which might actually have no particular connection to the fact that she won *other* Grammys for one specific album that won *Album of the year*. The cited text seems ambiguous on that possibility.#

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know that "1989" is the title of her album, and I infer that it won three grammys because "including album of the year" is a parenthetical clause, and should therefore be removable without altering the main meaning of "... she had three grammys for '1989'."  :-)

Comment: @Hellion I decided to check this out as you piqued my curiosity, concerning the grammar structure in OP's sentence. It turns out just two of the Grammys were for 1989. I've updated my answer with the details.

Comment: @Gary but "Bad Blood" is a track on "1989", so if you give the writer a little leeway, you could still say it's sort of true that all three Grammys were for "1989", even though it is clearly not technically accurate.  (And just in case anybody gets the wrong idea, I had to go look up the track list.  :-) )

Comment: @Hellion oh interesting I didn't know that, I would say it still needs more than a little leeway personally, and is bordering on being factually incorrect. But yes I see your point. (haha at your edit, yes we believe you!)

Comment: @Hellion: Actually, I was so preoccupied with the awkwardness of parsing ***for 1989*** in the slightly unusual context of it being an album name rather than just a year that I didn't take account of that all-important second comma. Your interpretation is obviously correct, and I was mistaken in supposing there's any ambiguity. Which just goes to show I don't keep up with every aspect of popular music - I now realise Swift was actually *born* in 1989, so she obviously wasn't winning Grammys that year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taylor Swift opened the show and by the time it ended she had three Grammys, including album of the year, for 1989.*

> I can't make out for 1989. What it means?

[1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_(Taylor_Swift_album)) is the name of one of Taylor Swift's albums:

> 1989 is the fifth studio album by American singer-songwriter Taylor
>   Swift released on October 27, 2014, through Big Machine Records...1989 won the Grammy Award for Album of the Year. - Wikipedia

[image]

> What means phrase to persevere and take credit for their own talents?

The music industry is very hard to break into. Taylor swift has 'made it', and is giving advice to *young women* that would like to break through into it. She is advising them to 'keep going' (i.e. persevere) in spite of any obstacles they might face, and to believe in themselves (take credit for their own talents).

***Edit:***

Following the comments under the question, debating if the Grammys were all won for 1989, I decided to do a little extra research.

The Grammy for the album 1989, was actually awarded in 2016.

From the Wikipedia listing for all [Grammy awards for album of the year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammy_Award_for_Album_of_the_Year):

> 2016 - Taylor Swift - 1989

Cross referencing with the actual Grammys awarded in 2016.

Taylor swift won:

1. Album of the year - for 1989.
2. Best pop vocal album - for 1989.
3. Best music video - for Bad Blood.

So in 2016, Taylor Swift received two Grammys for the album *1989*, and one for the music video *Bad Blood*.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. The first question "for 1989" was a little less straight-forward, but as Taylor swift wasn't singing in 1989, it had to be the name of an album. But it was certainly a tricky one your English course threw at you!

Comment: Can you see my third question?

Comment: That's actually a very simple question and you can answer that yourself, just check any dictionary. You should likely remove that edit also, or your question will likely be closed, as it demonstrates a real lack of research and initiative. Your other two questions in the context of your English course were fine though. Best of luck with your studies!